# React Native Modal With Status Bar Show

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I using `react-native 0.48.4` and using [react-native-phone-input](https://github.com/thegamenicorus/react-native-phone-input) for phone number input. I found the module have using `Modal`. When `Modal` show, `StatusBar` are hidden, I tried to set `StatusBar.setHidden(false);` , `StatusBar` still hidden. How do make the `StatusBar` show when `Modal` called.

```
<Modal
  animationType={'slide'}
  transparent
  visible={this.state.modalVisible}
  onRequestClose={() => {console.log("Country picker has been closed.")}}
>

</Modal>
```

Comment: Same thing is happening to me... Only on Android.
Any news regarding this issue?

Comment: Have you tried adding <StatusBar /> wherever you're using your Modal component?

Answer (score -2):

Personally i'm using the [react-native modal](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-modal) repository provided by the react community for my modals implementation.

It handles a lot of default behaviour and provides a lot of feature, fully hackable.

When using this lib, to solve your problem, it would be a simple :

```
<Modal style={style.modal}>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text>Hello!</Text>
  </View>
</Modal>
```

I personally apply this styling

```
modal: {
 backgroundColor: 'white',
 marginHorizontal: 0,
 marginBottom: 0,
 borderBottomLeftRadius: 0,
 borderBottomRightRadius: 0,
 borderTopLeftRadius: 10,
 borderTopRightRadius: 10,
 overflow: 'hidden',
}
```

To have something like:

[image]

[image]

I hope this answer will help you. Do not hesitate to ask more questions if you need further details.

Comment: it still hide the StatusBar

Comment: It because the <Modal> from react-native modal have a margin by default.
If you still want to use the basic Modal API, just add a marginTop to your modal.

Comment: set the marginTop also same, it hidden the StatusBar

Comment: i checked the `index.js` in `react-native-modal`, it also used `Modal` from `react-native`, so using `react-native-modal` is not helping, any other suggest ?

Comment: Well. you clearly have a styling issue on your side because i succeed to implement it on my side, and it seems like basic react-native-phone-input implementation succeeds as well.
Can't help you more than this. Good luck !

Comment: did you try android ?

Comment: I did update my answer. Works fine both on iOS and Android.
Also tested on real device (iphone6, iphoneSE, samsung A5 2016, samsung galaxy s8).

Comment: and how your modal prop set

Comment: react-native's out of the box Modal is unfortunately garbage, and is full of bugs I am using react-native-modal as well.